# How to retrieve more than 50 results using youtube api in R

Tags: r, youtube-api

I am working on a school project in R where I am attempting to map where the most popular youtube videos are posted around the world. I am able to get the data for the 50 most popular videos, but am having trouble understanding how to use pageToken.

The current get request I am using is with the following:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videospart=snippet%2CrecordingDetails&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&key={api_key}

Is it possible to retrieve more than 50 results using "pageToken" (I am unfamiliar with how this works).

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#request)
>
> pageToken string
>  The pageToken parameter identifies a specific
> page in the result set that should be returned. In an API response,
> the nextPageToken and prevPageToken properties identify other pages
> that could be retrieved.
>
> Note: This parameter is supported for use in conjunction with the
> myRating parameter, but it is not supported for use in conjunction
> with the id parameter.

So when you get the results from the first request you should have an option called page token if you send that to the next request

```
&pageToken=api_pageToken
```

it should give you the next bunch of rows.

Note: I am not an R programmer so I cant help with the code for a loop over the results to find out if there are page tokens or not.